# Laptop fails to suspend

Tags: 14.04, suspend, wakeup

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my mothers's rather old machine and I am facing an odd problem. The computer can't suspend. The screen turns off well but when the PC should suspend, the screen wakes up. Same thing happens when I use `pm-suspend`, the screen turns off not even a second, some lines appear on the screen to fast for me to read them, and the screen turns on.

I checked `acpitool -w` and here is the result

```
  1. LANC     S4    *disabled
  2. P32      S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
  3. KBC      S3    *enabled   pnp:00:03
  4. MOUE     S3    *disabled  pnp:00:04
  5. CIR0     S5    *enabled   pnp:00:05
  6. EXP2     S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
  7. PXSX     S5    *enabled   pci:0000:03:00.0
  8. EXP6     S0    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.5
  9. PXSX     S0    *disabled
```

I managed to disable through an upstart script KBC and CIR0, with no luck. PXSX stays enabled despite of the script.

I tried as well to disconnect all the usb devices linked to the computer, nothing changed.

Here is the last entry of the `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` file after I executed the `pm-suspend` command. I tried to understand it but it is above my linux understanding.

```
mercredi 9 mars 2016, 10:37:43 (UTC+0100): performing suspend
sh: echo: I/O error
mercredi 9 mars 2016, 13:37:43 (UTC+0100): Awake.
mercredi 9 mars 2016, 13:37:43 (UTC+0100): Running hooks for resume
Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/novatel_3g_suspend resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/98video-quirk-db-handler resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95led resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend:

/dev/sda:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
 APM_level  = 254
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95hdparm-apm resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/95anacron resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/90clock resume suspend: not applicable.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend:
Reloaded unloaded modules.
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/75modules resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend:
Selected interface 'wlan0'
OK
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/60_wpa_supplicant resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/50unload_alx resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend: success.

Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend:
/etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00logging resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000record-status resume suspend: success.

Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/000kernel-change resume suspend: success.

mercredi 9 mars 2016, 13:37:44 (UTC+0100): Finished.
```

Just in case of I updated my video card drivers as well, cause I had no idea what else to do.

And here is the summary of hardinfo

```
-Computer-
Processor       : 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P7350  @ 2.00GHz
Memory      : 4044MB (753MB used)
Operating System        : Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
User Name       : freddie (Freddie)
Date/Time       : mer. 09 mars 2016 13:44:09 CET
-Display-
Resolution      : 1280x800 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : GeForce 9600M GT/PCIe/SSE2
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation
-Multimedia-
Audio Adapter       : HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
-Input Devices-
 Power Button
 Lid Switch
 Sleep Button
 Power Button
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
 SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
 Video Bus
 ENE eHome Infrared Remote Receiver
 MCE IR Keyboard/Mouse (ene_ir)
 ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer
 HDA Intel Dock Mic
 HDA Intel Mic
 HDA Intel Front Headphone
 HDA Intel HDMI/DP,pcm      : 3 Phantom=
 HP WMI hotkeys
 Logitech M315/235/317
 Logitech K230
 HP Webcam
-Printers-
No printers found
-SCSI Disks-
ATA TOSHIBA MK3252GS
TSSTcorp CDDVDW TS-L633L
SanDisk Cruzer Blade
```

Thanks for any help you could provide, if anything else is needed I'd be happy to provide more infos.

Comment: Can you hibernate?

Comment: Yes but there is two weird things happening, I'm not sure it is relevant. First my usb keyboard doesn't work in the grub (it usually does). Second , right after the hibernation the screen is ugly (no menu bar, weird launcher...) and I have to pass the mouse over each element to make them look normal again.